# how to get all values of editext in custom listview editext from mysql database in android

Tags: android, android-listview

i am fetching the menunames from mysql database and append to edittext in custom listview using base adapter.now i am change some menunames in editext values. now i want get all editext from first to last

```
            Eg:x,y,z,.... are menunames coming from database it append editext(cusom listview)
            i am change editext value y to b
            now i want x,b,z...... values in arraylisst..
```

my base adapger class

```
public class EditMainMenulistview extends BaseAdapter {
    public final ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    protected static Context Context = null;
    int i;
    public String editnewmainmenu, menuname, edittext;
    String qrimage;
    Bitmap bmp, resizedbitmap;
    Bitmap[] bmps;
    Activity activity = null;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private ImageView[] mImages;
    String[] itemimage;
    TextView[] tv;
    String itemname, itemcode;
    public String[] itemnames, itemcodes;
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public EditMainMenulistview(Context context, JSONArray imageArrayJson) {
        Context = context;
        // inflater =
        // (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length()];
        this.bmps = new Bitmap[imageArrayJson.length()];
        this.itemnames = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];
        this.itemcodes = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];

        try {

            for (i = 0; i < imageArrayJson.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
                qrimage = image.getString("menuimage");
                itemname = image.getString("menuname");
                itemcode = image.getString("menucode");
                itemnames[i] = itemname;
                itemcodes[i] = itemcode;

                byte[] qrimageBytes = Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes());

                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes, 0,
                        qrimageBytes.length);
                int width = 100;
                int height = 100;
                resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height,
                        true);
                bmps[i] = bmp;

                mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);
                mImages[i].setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);

                mImages[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);

                // tv[i].setText(itemname);
            }
            System.out.println(itemnames[i]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mImages.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editmainmenulist, null);
            holder.caption = (EditText) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.editmaimenu);
            holder.caption1 = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.menuimage);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        // Fill EditText with the value you have in data source
        holder.caption.setText(itemnames[position]);//i append menunames here
        holder.caption.setId(position);
        holder.caption1.setImageBitmap(bmps[position]);

        // we need to update adapter once we finish with editing
        arr.add(holder.caption.getText().toString());//here i am try to get all values change and without edit text values but it get only menunames values

        return convertView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    EditText caption;
    ImageView caption1;
}

class ListItem {
    String caption;
}
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to Use `OnTouch` for `EditText` to get it Id and add `TextWatcher` to get Editext in that EditText.

Here is Example for Touch Listener in EditText

```
OnTouchListener mEdittextTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int childPosition =  v.getId;
        Log.i("Log_tag", "Edittext Position is " + childPosition);
                   //Here you will get your EditText Position.
        //saveData=true;
        //setChildPosition(childPosition);

        return false;
    }
};
```

Now implements `TextWatcher` in your Activity and add modification like this in getView of your `BaseAdapter`.

```
 holder.caption.removeTextChangedListener(ExpandableListPage.this);
 holder.caption.setOnTouchListener(mEdittextTouchListener);
 holder.caption.addTextChangedListener(ExpandableListPage.this);
```

now make sure to first remove TextWatcher from EditText and add it .Because when your listview view is going to show EditText will call TextWather Method ,to prevent this we always need to Remove it and then add it.

```
    @Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    Log.v("Log_tag", "After TextChanged" + s.toString());


}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    Log.i("Log_tag", "Before TextChanged" + s.toString());

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    Log.e("Log_tag", "ontext Changed"+ s.toString());
    if(count!=0){
        if(saveData){
            //Add your EditText Change Value here 
                           arr.add(s.toString());
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: i tried ur code but i am getting errors. please see my code add ur code let me post once again

Comment: When you want to edit in EditText do you need to Touch that EditText in Listview ,if it required then we can get Edittext is from onTouch and by using TextWatcher we can get change in that EditText.now let me known where you get Problem.

Comment: why ur giving  saveData variable.. please tell me